# Repeated values when inserting rows into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have problems on inserting rows into a `JTable` and I don't know what the problem is.

I do exactly like this:

```
((DefaultTableModel)myJTable.getModel()).insertRow(0,webSiteDownloader.getWebSites().toArray());
```

The `webSiteDownloader` is one object that have an `ArrayList`. I can get that array calling the method `getWebSites`.

The problem is that when I insert one row, adding the second one, the `JTable` only shows the first one, but repeated twice. Was I clear enough?

Thks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a shot into the dark and guess that you want to accomplish something like this:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)myJTable.getModel();
for (MyRowObject row : webSiteDownloader.getWebSites()) {
  dtm.insertRow(0, row.toArray());
}
```

Is there a special reason that you're using insertRow instead of addRow?

Also, I'd really like to recommend that you roll your own special purpose TableModel by extending AbstractTableModel. Basic untested example:

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
  protected List<MyObject> rows;

  public MyTableModel()
  {
    rows = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
  }

  public void add(MyObject obj)
  {
    rows.add(obj);
  }

  @Override
  public int getRowCount()
  {
    return rows.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getColumnCount()
  {
    // This value will be constant, but generally you'd also
    // want to override getColumnName to return column names
    // from an array, and in that case you can return the length
    // of the array with column names instead
    return 2;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
  {
    MyObject obj = rows.get(row);

    // Change this to match your columns
    switch(column) {
      case 0: return obj.getId();
      case 1: return obj.getName();
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Icky code. Non-standard formatting. Protected. Missing final. Initialisation in a constructor when it could be done on the declaration line. Some return, some unhandled in a switch. Returning a random (`null`) value instead of throwing an exception. Missing @Override.

Comment: Your TableModel can't work if you don't call the inherited fireXxxxEvent() methods from AbstractTableModel! Any call to add() won't refresh the JTable!

Comment: Also true. I'm sorry for all the silly misstakes, here. It was only meant as a basic example to illustrate the principle and as a basic help to get started, so I wasn't a thorough as I should have been.